# FLutter List Listen to Changes and save to sharedpreferences

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences

Im wondering if there is a way to listen to any changes made to a list and update/save it on *sharedpreferences*. That way I can avoid not saving if the user closes the app or calling functions to update *sharedpreferences* when user adds/updates/deletes anything from the list.

This is my list:

```
LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<CalEvent>> _events = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<CalEvent>>();
```

imagine we start with an empty list, then user adds something to list, i want to get notified that 'something added to the list' and calls function to update/save it on sharedpreferences.

Thanks, please bare with me as i am fairly new with flutter.

Comment: You can add https://pub.dev/packages/get and use `RxList` instead of List, and then listen to `RxList` change.

Comment: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams